# How to remove extensions icons from Chrome toolbar and menu

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

As we know in the past only extension that has "browser_action:default_icon" in its manifest file was displayed on the Chrome toolbar. But recently, Google Chrome displays icons of all the extensions on its toolbar even if I install old version of the browser. How to disable this feature even removing it from the Chrome source code? I don't mean how to hide the icons by moving them from the toolbar to the Chrome menu. I mean how to remove this feature at all or at least hide unwanted icons both on the toolbar and the menu?

**UPDATE 28/11/2017:** The question is still actual. Does anyone know where is the line(s) in resource.pak or another file showing extension icons in Chrome toolbar AND Chrome menu?

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about it here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597657
and an older discussion:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=397259

The security reasoning is very weak imho...

Here's the bugtrack which removed the old code:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=590321